# regex vs split to cut the strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

```
var str = "in this sentence, I WANT TO GET ONLY THIS PART - not the other parts"
```

Assume I want to get the part which is starts with `,` and ends with `-`

I always use `split` in order to cut or get the sub-sentence. Because I don't know how to write a `regex`.

For this example I wrote as;

```
str.split(",")[1].split("-")[0]
" I WANT TO GET ONLY THIS PART "
```

Is it efficient to use `split`? Or how can I write a regex which will take the same part. Which one should I choose? `regex` or `split`? What do you suggest and why?

edit: Thank you for giving me the exact regex, but I also want to know which way is better? Using split is also a solution? Or should I learn how to write a regex?

Comment: Hi, First of all you need to answer a few qestions : **1)** Will your string remain the same? **2)** You always have to separate the string that is AllCaps?

Comment: Actually allCaps is just for emphasizing the string that I want to cut. There is no need for it. I just want to get string between "," and "-" for example.

Comment: You could use `.split()` *with* a regex: `str.split(/[,-]/)[1]`. Or `str.split(/(?:, *)|(?: *-)/)[1]` to avoid the leading and trailing spaces. (I'm not saying you *should*, but you *could*...)

Comment: @nnnnnn thank you! I have never see using split with regex, this is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following *regex* :

```
,\s?(.*?)\s?-
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var str = "in this sentence, I WANT TO GET ONLY THIS PART - not the other parts";
var result = str.match(/,\s?(.*?)\s?-/);
console.log(result[1]);
```

Comment: result will be `<space>RESULT<space>`

Comment: +1 for the fix.. yet, this will fail when the result needed contains `,` or `-` maybe get first index of `,` then last index of `-`? :D